# Basic calculator, how to make buttons input value to text field

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

I am beginner with JavaScript, I am doing this basic calculator, finally managed to make it look the way I want, but I am really struggling on how to make buttons "work" - input their value into text field. I can use only JavaScript for this. Tried figuring it out by googling, but there's something I don't understand, because I tried several ways and it still doesn't work. Please help me on this and explanation would be highly appreciated, since I want to understand it as well :)

HTML:

```
<div class="calculator">
<div class="screen"><input type=text name="display" id="display" 
disabled></div>
<div><input type="button" name= "seven" value="7"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="eight" value="8"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="nine" value="9"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="divide" value="/"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="four" value="4"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="five" value="5"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="six" value="6"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="multiply" value="*"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="one" value="1"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="two" value="2"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="three" value="3"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="minus" value="-"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="clear" value="C"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="zero" value="0"></div>
<div><input type="button" name="equal" value="="></div>
<div><input type="button" name="plus" value="+"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.calculator {
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 35px 35px 35px 35px 35px;
grid-template-columns: 35px 35px 35px 35px;
}
.screen {
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 5;
}
input[type="button"] {
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
}
input[type="text"] {
width: 140px;
height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Please show something you tried, then we can help you understand where you went wrong and how to fix it. We're not going to write it for you from scratch.

Comment: Hint: In the event listener you can get the button's value with `this.value`.

Comment: Please post what you've tried, a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a beginner, you might want to take a look at [for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) and [event listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) to better understand this solution.

---

**The solution:**

Add an `eventListener` to every of your buttons, so you can fire some function that does what the button on a "real" calculator would do.

```js
// Get all your buttons
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"');

// Get your input field
var input = document.getElementById('display');

// Add a eventListener to every button
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() { // when a button gets clicked, an function will fire
    input.value += this.value; // 'this' is the button that gets clicked. We add its value to the input field
  });
}
```

```css
.calculator {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 35px 35px 35px 35px 35px;
  grid-template-columns: 35px 35px 35px 35px;
}

.screen {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

input[type="button"] {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 140px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="screen"><input type=text name="display" id="display" disabled></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="seven" value="7"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="eight" value="8"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="nine" value="9"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="divide" value="/"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="four" value="4"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="five" value="5"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="six" value="6"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="multiply" value="*"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="one" value="1"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="two" value="2"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="three" value="3"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="minus" value="-"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="clear" value="C"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="zero" value="0"></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="equal" value="="></div>
  <div><input type="button" name="plus" value="+"> </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that you will need to handle your `=`, `+`, `-`, `/`, `*` and `C` buttons differently! Otherwise you will just add their value to your input field.

Comment: Thank you so much, helped a lot, I started to understand what I am missing :)